# Trying to turn function into script

Tags: function, powershell, scripting

I have a function I'm trying to turn into a running script.

```
$string = New-Object.CustomTitleCase
$InputString = $String

{ $string = read-host -prompt "Please give me a title to Correct."
    if ($String -contains 
        'are','to','a','the','at','in','of','with','and','but','or') 
        ( $InputString -split " " |ForEach-Object {
        if ($_ -notin $NoCapitalization) {
            "$([char]::ToUpper($_[0]))$($_.Substring(1))"
            if $string -contains "-AllCaps "string".ToUpper()
        } else { $_ }
    }) -join " "
}
Pause
```

Comment: What is your script supposed to do exactly? (Obviously, you want to do string manipulation but could you provide an input sample and expected output based on it?)

Comment: Oh Yes that would be helpfull

Comment: sorry im trying to make a script that would have you input a title of a movie for example and then it would give it back only with proper capitalization like gone with the wind to Gone With the Wind. also adding a -AllCaps option to make it all caps.

Comment: I think you got that `-contains` comparison backwards. Should be `$Collection -contains $Item` not the other way around

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want something like this:

```
function Format-Title {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [String]$InputString,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [Switch]$AllCaps
    )

    $NoCapitalization = @('are', 'to', 'a', 'the', 'at', 'in', 'of', 'with', `
                          'and', 'but', 'or')

    $Words = $String -split ' '
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $Words.Count; $i++) {
        if ( ($i -eq 0) `
         -or ($AllCaps) `
         -or ($NoCapitalization -notcontains $Words[$i]) ) {
            $FirstLetter = $Words[$i].Substring(0,1)
            $Words[$i] = $FirstLetter.ToUpper() + $Words[$i].Substring(1)
        }
    }

    return $Words -join ' '
}
```

Logic:

- always capitalize the first word
- if `-AllCaps` switch is specified, capitalize all words
- otherwise skip words included in the $NoCapitalization collection

Example:

```
Format-Title -InputString "gone with the wind" -AllCaps
```

Output:

```
Gone With The Wind
```

Comment: that doesn't work right I've tried to tweek it a little but no dice.

Comment: The code should be obvious enough but I added Logic section to the answer to make absolutely sure we're on the same page. If this logic isn't what you want, the question is: what _do_ you want? )